# Remove Parameter From Product url Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, url

I am trying to remove parameter(#857=) from the product url:

https://tpm2.redsignal.net/reina-modal-trv-steel-radiator-towel-rail-valve-anthracite.html#857=

[image]

These parameter are of configuration values but i want to remove it from my products url.

Please help me i can't find any solution.